# Allow users to see restricted nodes via views

Tags: views, 6, users

I have a content type with meta data about a department, and these nodes is restricted using Taxonomy Access Control so that only the department heads can actually view them.  I would like to create a view of *some* of the information in these nodes that will be visible to people without full view rights to the node, but views filters out nodes that the current user can't see, which means that these nodes are hidden for non-department heads.  Is there a way to override the node access filtering for a specific view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've not used Taxonomy Access Control, but I'd look in Views' Advanced Settings / Query Settings and check Disable SQL rewriting. But, as the warning says, "Disabling SQL rewriting means that node access security is disabled. This may allow users to see data they should not be able to see if your view is misconfigured. Please use this option only if you understand and accept this security risk."

Comment: That's exactly what I want, alas I'm stuck on views 2 for the time being.  Thanks though!

Comment: To follow up, the best option for me right now was just to make these nodes accessible, and hide the body/cck fields in a preprocess function if the user is under privileged.  Not great, but will be passable until i can update views.